# Is there a way to determine an element's page number in Google Docs - DocumentApp service

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm building a reporting system that sends data to multiple clients with data from an Airtable database.

Everything works great - except:

The report includes a series of tables with variable lengths (number of rows). There is no way to force a table to stay on a single page.

As a workaround, is there any way to return/find what page a given element is on?

With this information I could get the page number of the first and last row of a table. If they are different, add a page break before the table.

Thanks for any ideas and direction.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no method to get the page of an item. As you can see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36755897), there is a Feature Request to add this functionality. You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the request.

As a workaround,  you can add a page break for each table that contains more than x rows.

```js
function gDocsInsertEveryTable() {
 var body = DocumentApp.openById(DOCUMENT_ID).getBody()
 // Get all tables
 var tables = body.getTables()
 for (let table of tables) {
   // Loop and add a pageBreak after each table
   if (table.getNumRows() > 30) {
     table.getPreviousSibling().asParagraph().insertPageBreak(0)
   }
 }
}
```

##### Documentation

- [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app)

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that and was hoping for a better workaround that I may have missed. Right now, as the document has a few different pieces of information, I'm left determining height/space used of various items to "guess" when/where to add a page break. 

I can't simply use number of rows because other/prior elements also impact that. I'll upvote the feature request.